# How do I get R to show me the frequency of each variable in a character vector?

Tags: r, vector, character, dplyr

I am analyzing a spreadsheet of 181,000+ user actions and am interested to know how many actions each user performed. I want R to show me how many times a particular user's name appears, ranked from highest to lowest, so that I can focus on the users performing the most actions (we are not really interested in users that perform, say, ten actions, when our most active user performed 101,554 in the past week). I have created the character vector new.variable.v to select the "screen_name" column of the spreadsheet, and

```
table(table(new.variable.v))
```

shows me counts, but not screen names. Every other solution I've read seems geared to identifying the number of times a particular instance occurs, whereas I want to know the number of times each different screen name occurs. A more R-adept friend suggested some other things, copied from my console with their error messages:

```
new.variable.sort[order(new.variable.sort[,2], decreasing=TRUE),]
```

> Error in `[.default`(new.variable.sort, , 2) :    incorrect number of
> dimensions

```
new.variable.order <- count(new.variable.v)
```

> Error in UseMethod("group_by_") :    no applicable method for
> 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"

```
count(new.variable.v, x) %>%
    arrange(desc(n))
```

> Error in UseMethod("group_by_") :    no applicable method for
> 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"

I've googled these errors and read some other Stack Overflow entries about them, but I have not been able to produce a successful outcome.

Comment: Hi Sam!  Welcome to SO.  Can you provide a reproducible example (say, a data frame definition with just a handful of example rows)?

Comment: You mean like this?> table(new.variable.v)
new.variable.v
-MakesSense-     12AIM784       12blue      12for14       1423cd 2011Rainmakr   37Tomate37       400000         4200 
         314           12            1            1            5          756            3            2           11 
    427Cobra      47Steve        50Cal       54p095       a_go_c     aatkadam       AAUSA7     AbackCab  AbackChum35 
           1          143            1            3            5            7            2            1            2 
 AbackDate24   AbackEar10  AbackEase28  AbackLink18  AbackNest98

Comment: > table(data$screen_name, sort=true)
Error in data$screen_name : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
> freq<- data%>% count(screen_name, sort = TRUE)
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"

  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: it's most helpful if we can actually *create* the data you're having a problem with, not just see what your outputs are.  For example, `data.frame(new.variable.v = c("A", "B", "C"))` .. You might benefit from giving http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example a read...

Comment: OK, how about (new.variable.v = c("EagerTape68", "EagerTape68", "jebinless3", "BoldOther94", "BoldOther94", "2011Rainmakr", "EagerTape68")) with that vector going on for 180K+ additional entries? Desired output from this example would be EagerTape68 = 3, BoldOther94 = 2, 2011Rainmakr = 1, jebinless3 = 1.

Comment: Would `table(new.variable.v)` not give you what you want? You can sort the output of `table()` fine. Something like this works: `sort(table(new.variable.v),decreasing=T)`.

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, dplyr / tidyverse style, approach would be to first read the spreadsheet in to a dataframe using `df <- readxl::read_excel()`. Then, you can find the counts of screen_name with:

```
res <- df %>%
  group_by(screen_name) %>%
  summarise(volume = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(volume))
```

I personally like this approach because I work in [RStudio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RStudio), and outputting the results as a dataframe lets me easily view and play around with it.